# error: no matching function for call to 'QNetworkAccessManager::QNetworkAccessManager(Networking* const)'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

This is my files. I have some problems with that.

```
   // networking.h

#ifndef NETWORKING_H
#define NETWORKING_H

#include <QNetworkReply>

class Networking
{
public:
    Networking();
    void getNetReply();
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply*);
};

#endif // NETWORKING_H




//networking.cpp
#include "networking.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QObject>

Networking::Networking()
{
}

void Networking::getNetReply(){
    QNetworkAccessManager * man;
    man = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    qDebug() << "Getting content..." << endl;

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://www.google.pl"));
    qDebug() << "Network request..." << endl;

    QNetworkReply * NetRepl;
    QObject::connect(man, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    NetRepl = man->get(request);
    qDebug() << "Network reply..." << endl;

    qDebug() << "Connecting..." << endl;

}

void Networking::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply){
    // my code
    reply->readAll();
}
```

My error messages. I have googled a lot and read the documentation:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   `QNetworkAccessManager::QNetworkAccessManager(Networking* const)`
>        `man = new QNetworkAccessManager(this)`;
>
> 20: error: no matching function for call to
>   `QObject::connect(QNetworkAccessManager*&, const char*, Networking*`
>   `const, const char*)`
>       `QObject::connect(man, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this,` `SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Q_OBJECT` macro  to your class without `;`

```
class Networking : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Networking();
    void getNetReply();
```

And rebuild all project

Without this macro `moc` cannot find your class and you can't use signals/slots mechanism. Also your class should be derivated from `QObject` explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Thank for answering. I still get those error messages